# URL requests containing "/#/" are all seen as "/" then failing when running on Locust.io

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

The requests containing "/#/" are all seen as "/". Then I'll get a ton of "fails".

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

@task(2)
def login_page(self):
    self.client.get("/")

@task(1)
def dashboard_page(self):
    self.client.get("/#/bubblesu")

@task(1)
def parents_page(self):
    self.client.get("/#/pages/parents")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
```

This is the result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnrmH.png)

There's no cmd errors in the prompt.

Then I tried to convince locust to name (and use) the proper ones.
However naming worked, but it looks like the request are still made against "/". So in result I'm not able to load test each request.

My developer says "The hash sign is there because it's a single page application
the path after that is just for routing via javascript. if you remove it the browser would try and find the page"

Here's the script

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    @task(2)
    def login_page(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task(1)
    def dashboard_page(self):
        self.client.get("/#/bubblesu", name='dashboard')

    @task(1)
    def parents_page(self):
        self.client.get("/#/pages/parents", name='parents')

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
```

Executing with this from cmd.

```
locust -f locustfile2.py --host=https://www.bubblesu.com
```

This is the URL to the login page.

```
https://bubblesu.com/#/bubblesu
```

This is what Locust shows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Lfx.png)

cmd has no errors displayed.

Using Windows 10, Pycharm

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"#" is a fragment identifier, so everything after it is stripped from the URI when sending an HTTP request.